# For which of the following fields $\mathbb F$ the polynomial $x^3-312312x+123123$ is irreducible in $\mathbb F[x]$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory

I came across the following problem:

> For which of the following fields $\mathbb F$ the polynomial  $x^3-312312x+123123$ is irreducible in $\mathbb F[x]$? The options are
>   $1.$ the field $\mathbb F_3$ with $3$ elements.
>   $2.$ the field $\mathbb F_7$ with $7$ elements.
>   $3.$ the field $\mathbb F_{13}$ with $13$ elements.
>   $4.$ the field $\mathbb Q$ of rational numbers.

Can someone point me in the right direction with some explanation? Thanks in advance for your time.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Hint 1** Both coefficients are divisible by $3,7$ and $13$. So what is your poly in those finite fields?

**Hint 2** $3|123123$ and $312312$ but $9$ doesn't divide $123123$.

Answer (score 5):

**Hint:** For the first three problems, find the relevant divisors of our big numbers.

Eisenstein the fourth problem.

Answer (score 3):

Hint: Since you are dealing with a degree three polynomial, it will be irreducible if and only if it doesn't have a root. For 1-3 since you're fields are of prime order, they are just $\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}$ for whichever prime is relevant. You can check by hand whether or not your polynomial has a root in these fields. For 4. you have the Rational Root Theorem at your disposal.

Answer (score 2):

If we take field $\mathbb F_3$, then the polynomial become $x^3$ (since other coefficients are divisible by $3$). Same for $\mathbb F_7$ and $\mathbb F_{13}$, and $x^3$ is not irreducible. So only $(d)$ is correct.

Comment: How do you know that (d) is correct without proving this?